# Read file with ClassLoader

Tags: java, android, classloader

I have a file published in my `files` folder in android.

I can correctly load it by calling `new ClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/myFile")`.

The problem is that I need to call it via `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)`

I tried many ways:

`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/myFile")`
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/myFile.extension")`
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myFile")`
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myFile")`
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/myFile")`
`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/myFile.extension")`

Every single case returned me `null`.

I need to use that method because I have to call an external lib that uses it, but I can't figure out what should I pass as file name/path to make it work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

---

Folder structure:

"main" package:

```
com/company/customer/project/activities/MyActivity.java
```

Class package:

```
customer/project/helper.java
```

`Helper.java` file is called by `MyActivity.java` and runs the `getClassLoader()` code.

That's my files folder path:

```
 getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(); 
 //it results in 
 "/data/user/0/com.company.customer.project.flavor.dev/files"
```

Comment: what is your folder structure

Comment: @DoctorWho added :)

Comment: where is this `files` folder located

Comment: @DoctorWho added it also

Comment: If it isn't a resource located via the CLASSPATH you can't use the `getResource()` method family to locate it.

Comment: @user207421 sorry but I didn't understand, what should I do to make this file visible for the contextclassloader retriever?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley your third party lib expect what kind of response, is it InputStream or something else

Comment: @DoctorWho my library only wants as input the file name. it works in javaEE but on android it doesn't find the file..